# Как вывести все значения из столбца

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

У меня есть база данных wordpress, в ней таблица wp_terms. Нужно вывести все значения из этой таблицы из столбца name.
Используемые функции выводят лишь одно значение

```
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root','', 'wordpress');
mysqli_query( $link,"SET CHARSET utf8" );
$sql = "SELECT name FROM wp_terms";
$ready = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_row($ready);
    print_r($result);
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну так фетчи по одной, пока не кончатся...

Answer (score 0):

вам нужно добавить цикл while

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($ready)) {
    print($result["name"]);
}
```

Comment: Добавьте объяснение, что у автора не так, и почему ваш вариант работает.